# What things to watch out for when installing a secondary HDD

Tags: hard-drive

I have a pretty old machine on which I would like to upgrade the hard drive. The Machine has an 
AMD Athlon 64bit 3400+ processor (2.2GHz) with a 80 GB 7200rpm Hitachi hard drive.I would like to go for a 1 TB hard drive. Please point out if there are any specific things i need to look out for. Also, any advice on whether to use the new hard drive as a slave or use it with RAID 1 configuration will be helpful.

Comment: Both a very subjective/argumentative and also too localized question. I don't see the real value that any person but you will gain from it. You would also need to be more specific: What do you use the machine for? Why shouldn't you just be able to buy a drive? Note that we don't give shopping recommendations. How should *we* know if you need RAID 1 or not? Also, how do you want to realize a RAID 1 with an 80GB and a 1TB drive? Generally said, you don't need to look out for anything special, just that the drive has the right connector (see answer below).

Comment: The answer to your last question (asking for advice on configuration) depends on what your motivations are. For example, is the 80GB drive starting to fail? Then you may want to reinstall your OS on the new drive and move all your data there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Watch out for:
Does the motherboard support Sata (I assume the 1TB drive is sata and the old disk is IDE)

[image: Sata vs ide image]

Also you cannot make a RAID configuration with a 80 GB disk and a disk of 1 TB. you would need 2 disks with 1TB for that.

If you use a SATA disk, master and slave is not important. Just set your boot sequence in the BIOS correctly.

Comment: You could make a partial RAID 1 configuration with differently-sized drives; it would simply take the size of the smaller drive, and the rest of the larger drive could be partitioned in a SLED configuration.